# Why does TreeNodeCollection not implenent IEnumerable<TreeNode>?

Tags: .net, winforms

TreeNodeCollection, like some of the other control collections in System.Windows.Forms, implements IEnumerable.  Is there any design reason behind this or is it just a hangover from the days before generics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are many .NET Framework collection, that does not implement generic IEnumerable.

I think that's because after 2.0 there was no (at least not so match) development of the core part of FW.

Meanwhile I suggest you to make use of following workaround:

```
using System.Linq; 
... 
var nodes = GetTreeNodeCollection().OfType<TreeNode>();
```

Comment: public class TreeNodeCollection : IList, ICollection, IEnumerabl  Why do you say "not implement generic IEnumerable"? BTY, your code works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Windows Forms dates back to before generics in .Net